# Identify if a buffer is CtrlP or not

Tags: vimrc, filetype, plugin-ctrlp, plugin-tagbar

I use a `autocmd` to display current tag via `Tabgar` plugin like this:

```
autocmd CursorHold * call TagbarCurrentTag
```

However, after I open `CtrlP` with `:CtrlP` for a while, the `Tagbar`'s output `No current tag` will overwrite the input area of `CtrlP`.

So I need to identify if I am in a `CtrlP` buffer to avoid displaying current tag. Maybe use `filetype`?

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Comment: Did you manage to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The CtrlP buffer has the name `ControlP`, so you should just be able to check this:

```
autocmd CursorHold * if bufname("%") != 'ControlP' | call TagbarCurrentTag() | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this problem, more or less. I had a similar issue with some `CursorMoved` autocommands that were rendering `CtrlP` unusable; the author claims that [when CtrlP is opened all autocommands are disabled](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/543) but it seems the suite of `Cursor*` autocommands are not included in this list.

Here is my workaround:

```
function! EIoff()
  set eventignore=
endfunction
function! EIon()
  set eventignore=CursorHold,CursorHoldI,CursorMoved,CursorMovedI,TextChanged,TextChangedI
endfunction
function! EImap()
  nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Esc> :q<CR>:EIoff<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <C-c> :q<CR>:EIoff<CR>
endfunction
command! EIon call EIon()
command! EIoff call EIoff()
command! EImap call EImap()
nnoremap <silent> <C-p> :EIon<CR>:CtrlP<CR>:EImap<CR>
let g:ctrlp_map=''
augroup eirestore
  au!
  au BufEnter * call EIoff()
augroup END
```

Basically, we override the default `<C-p>` mapping. The `EImap` command sends a mapping to the CtrlP buffer (notice it comes after the `:CtrlP`), so that if we re-enter the original buffer, the `Cursor*` autocommands are turned back on. Cancelling CtrlP completion and re-entering the original buffer does not seem to trigger the `BufEnter` autocommand. But if you open a *new* file, the `BufEnter` autocommand will indeed be triggered (hence the new autocommand).

Using simply `:noautocmd CtrlP` did not work. Using the enter/exit CtrlP functions  (for example, `let g:ctrlp_buffer_func={'enter':'EIon', 'exit':'EIoff'}`; see documentation) did not work. Using `nnoremap <C-p> :CtrlP<CR>:setlocal eventignore=CursorMoved,CurHold...<CR>` did not work for me because one of my autocommands was triggered right away upon entering the CtrlP buffer, resulting in an immediate error. Entering the buffer-local map of `<Esc>` as part of my `<C-p>` map à la `nnoremap <C-p> :CtrlP<CR>:nnoremap <Esc> <stuff>` also doesn't work because the `<Esc>` wants to be interpreted literally by the "parent" map of `<C-p>`.

It was a pretty challenging/perplexing problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `g:ctrlp_buffer_func` didn't work?

Comment: @Rich No idea why. But after setting the variable as above, I had the same problems. Anyway now I use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) and my life is happier.